# How to set the Object local axis as Global Axis

Tags: animation, rigging, transforms, axis, transform-orientation

[image]I am following a tutorial of rigging a car in blender for UE5 in that he told me that all parts of car should be oriented to global x and y axis can anyone give me how to change the axis step by step i have tried using transform option intools but cant align it perfectly step by step video would be highly helpful

Comment: So do you want to do something so that the x and y axis of every object is the same as the global x and y axis?

Comment: Apply the rotation (Ctrl A)?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take screenshots of camera apps taking photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.